# How to apply additional search query to LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have an LDAP server over SSL on my local machine and connecting it from the same machine from my application. Following is the code for connecting LDAP server:

```
// Specify the search scope
    final String returnedAtts[] = { ldapSettingModel.getDepartment(),
            ldapSettingModel.getEmailId(), ldapSettingModel.getLocation(),
            ldapSettingModel.getRole(), ldapSettingModel.getDispName() };
    String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=*)(" + ldapSettingModel.getLoginId() + "=" + user
            + ")" + ldapSettingModel.getFilter() + ")";

    String adPrincipal = user;
    if (CATAppConstants.ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_WIN_2000_ATTR.equals(ldapSettingModel.getLoginId())) {

        // with domain
        if (user.indexOf("\\") > 0) {
            user = user.substring(user.indexOf("\\") + 1);
            searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=*)(" + ldapSettingModel.getLoginId() + "=" + user
                    + ")" + ldapSettingModel.getFilter() + ")";
        } else {
            String[] pDN = ldapSettingModel.getBaseDNName().split(",");
            for (String dn : pDN) {
                if (dn.indexOf("dc=") == 0) {
                    adPrincipal = dn.substring(3) + "\\" + adPrincipal;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Create the search controls
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    String ldapProtocol = "ldap" + (ldapSettingModel.getSslFlg() == 1 ? "s" : "");
    String providerUrl = ldapProtocol + "://" + ldapSettingModel.getHost() + ":"
            + ldapSettingModel.getPortNo();
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
    if (ldapSettingModel.getSslFlg() == 1) {
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket",
                "com.shift.tcm.serviceCust.authenticationManagement.CustomSSLSocketFactory");
    }
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    switch (ldapSettingModel.getLdapType()) {
    case CATAppConstants.DIRECTORY_TYPE_IS_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY:
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, adPrincipal);
        break;
    default:
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapSettingModel.getLoginId() + "=" + user + ","
                + ldapSettingModel.getBaseDNName());
        break;
    }

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, requestPassword);
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", CATAppConstants.LDAP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT + "");

    LdapContext ctxGC = null;
    MstUserModel userDetails = null;

    // This is the actual Authentication piece. Will throw
    // javax.naming.AuthenticationException
    // if the users password is not correct. Other exceptions may
    // include IO (server not found) etc.
    ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

    // Now try a simple search and get some attributes as defined in
    // returnedAtts
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctxGC.search(ldapSettingModel.getBaseDNName(),
            searchFilter, searchCtls);

    userDetails = getUserDetailsFromLDAP(answer, ldapSettingModel, checkDetailsOnly,
            currentRoleName);
    userDetails.setLoginId(user);
```

Everything works fine until I try to add the search filter using the `ldapSettingModel.getFilter()`. Normally without it, search filter would contain `(&(objectClass=*)(uid=vaibhav))` for following LDAP server:

[image: LDAPS server snapshot]

I'm trying to allow user to add their additional search filter using `ldapSettingModel.getFilter()`, the values I tried to search using:

1. (cn=India): final `searchFilter` -> (&(objectClass=*)(uid=vaibhav)(cn=India))
2. (objectClass=postalAddress)(cn=*India*): final `searchFilter` -> (&(objectClass=*)(uid=vaibhav)(objectClass=postalAddress)(cn=*India*))

I'm not sure if I'm correctly applying the additional search filter, but the `NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer` is returned null from my `getUserDetailsFromLDAP()` method. Please guide me if I'm doing something wrong as I'm very new to LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(&(objectClass=*)(uid=vaibhav)(cn=India))
```

This doesn't make sense. `cn` is short for 'common name'. You don't have users whose common name is 'India'.

It should be

```
(&(objectClass=*)(uid=vaibhav)(postalAddress=India))
```

In fact as you're looking for users it could be

```
(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=vaibhav)(postalAddress=India))
```

The second alternative you mention makes even less sense.

Comment: Ohh, thank you for the quick solution, actually I wanted to test whether the code I have written to add additional searchFilter would work or not. But as I have very little knowledge how it works I was trying something out randomly. Thank again for explanation...!